# How to get product variation in cart?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have some meal packages to sell. For example.
Chicken meal has variations: 10 pack, 14 pack, 18 pack.
I want to disable flat_rate:3 when people order 10 pack. But I don’t know how to get the variation.
My code is below:

```
function hide_one_delivery( $rates, $item_id ) {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $10_pack = 0;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
        $variation_data = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true );
        if( $variation_detail == "10 pack" ){
            $10_pack += 1;
        }
    }
    if ($10_pack > 0){
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_one_delivery', 100 );
```

It's not working. Can anyopne please help?

Answer (score 1):

Just look into the product array, and you can get the variation data from the product array.

```
function hide_one_delivery( $rates, $item_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
        //$product is a array, and 10-pack is the slug of the attribute name
        if ( $product['variation_id'] && in_array('10-pack', $product['variation']) ) {

            unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] );
            break;

        }

    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_one_delivery', 100, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to add the variation to your cart.php page. My example has a name because I name my Variation "PkgDesc" when I added it to the Cart Session. This is code that you need to add to the Cart.php page.

Add the line of code after the foreach() line (around line 48):

```
$pkgDesc= apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['variation'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Now add the code below after your product title (// Meta data) (around line 85)

```
echo ": ";

echo $pkgDesc['PkgDesc'];
```

Your Cart line item will now look like this:

Chicken meal: 10 pack